# How to make rounded corners to a layer or selection in GIMP 2.8?

Tags: gimp

I would like to have a round cornered hexagon, but i don't know how to do it in GIMP 2.8. I know how to do a hexagon, but not a round cornered one. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to get a selection with rounded corners (any shape) is to create the selection `n` pixels smaller than you need, then use "Grow selection" to enlarge it by `n` pixels.  The corners will then all have radius `n`.

Comment: Awesome! Just would like to add that if "creating the selection" is troublesome then like one can simply select the *Fuzzy Select Tool* to select the region of interest and then do **Shrink selection** by `n` pixels before doing **Grow selection** by `n` pixels again. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this question 8 years later like I did: another way to do it is go to Select -> Rounded Rectangle, then choose rounding radius in %

Comment: Worked for me. If there were a way to round by pixel quantity rather than percentage, this would be perfect.